# add long a vowel pure via tipaman package

Tags: ipe

I would like to add vowel number five

[image]

here is where you can download the script

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/tipa/tipa

Am i doing it properly

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,pdftext]{book}
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{1}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
  \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=black,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
%\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tipaman}
%---PACKAGES-------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\ipxitem{\textinvscripta :}{Inverted script A}%
  {}%
  {\tbs textinvscripta}{}{\PSG}{'041}

 \textipa{/ \textinvscripta : /}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is the `tipaman` package available?  Incidentally, in general `hyperref` should be the last of the packages loaded.

Comment: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/tipa/tipa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `\textlengthmark` which should replace your colons:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,pdftext]{book}
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{1}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=black,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
%\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tipaman}
%---PACKAGES-------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\ipxitem{\textinvscripta\textlengthmark}{Inverted script A (plus long)}%
  {}%
  {\tbs textinvscripta}{}{\PSG}{'041}

 \textipa{/\textinvscripta\textlengthmark/}

\end{document}
```